# 502 error when making API request on RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, heroku

I'm using the [Rest Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem to make GitHub API calls for a RoR dashboard application. I have done error handling for the API responses through the 'response.code' call method. ie:

```
if response.code == 502
    return 'unavailable'
end
```

However sometimes the app will error out and say something along the lines of:

```
RestClient error return 502
```

in the heroku error log which leads me to believe it is getting an error in making the call and thus my current error handling is not effective. The result is the page will not render and I will get an error page.

How can I build in error handling that resolves issues if the API call cannot be made an a response code isn't returned (assuming that is the issue)?

I appreciate your input so I can get a better understanding and ultimately become a better developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If RestClient is throwing an actual exception, you can just rescue it:

```
begin
  response = RestClient.get("whatever.com")
rescue RestClient::Error # Replace with the actual exception class
  return 'unavailable'
end
```

Comment: I will look at the logs next time I get the error and get the exact error message to see if this resource applies but it looks promising. Will update if needed.